# Would someone versed in relative motion consider it more accurate to say that a car slammed into, or collided with, a wall?

Tags: relative-motion

I've read that it's just as correct to think of A moving toward B (ie. A doesn't move, but B does) as it is to think about B as moving toward A (again, A doesn't move, but B does) or as the two moving toward each other.

If I imagine a universe in which only two objects exists - then that seems like it would be the case. However, in that universe there isn't really a point of reference to say whether one object isn't moving.

Is there a useful and accurate way to think about these kinds of relations?

Thank you
-Hal.

Comment: `in that universe there isn't really a point of reference`. Yes, there is. You'll have infinite points over each object which can be used as a reference point.

Comment: @Renan - That goes for every universe then?

Comment: I suppose that for a universe to lack points you could use for reference, it should lack... any points at all. I don't think such a universe would make sense.

Comment: @Renan - No it doesnt seem like it makes sense. Good point. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point may be chosen as a reference point, as speed is always relative to something else.
Let's imagine I'm driving on the highway, and I'm going 10mph relative to the car I'm overtaking. Unfortunately for me, the other car was moving at the speed limit(60mph) and there was a speed camera, which gave me a ticket for going 70mph relative to the camera.

If there were only 2 objects in a universe, the only things one could establish for sure is the speed of one object relative to the other(and vice versa), and the direction of movement. 
One can't establish that both(or neither) objects would be moving, because one can't define relative to what they are moving. And for describing speed, one needs a reference.

Comment: How would you respond to Renan's comment "I suppose that for a universe to lack points you could use for reference, it should lack... any points at all. I don't think such a universe would make sense"

Comment: If a universe by definition only has 2 objects, those are the only things one can use as reference points.
Unless space is defined, then one could also use every point in space as a reference. But using space as a reference wouldn't make sense here as for something in the universe it's unknowable where the "origin"/reference point is. If I were to be outside of the universe that wouldn't be the case.